# Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare throws an error message when I launch it

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I have installed Call of Duty 4:Modern Warfare on my Windows 8 laptop.  But when I open the game, it says "Call of Duty 4:Modern Warfare has stopped working properly". I have changed the compatibility to Windows XP(Service Pack 3) but the problem persists.

Comment: I've modified your question to ask about CoD4:MW, since Modern Warfare 4 isn't actually out yet.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Emperor: Battle for Dune on my 64-bit Windows 7 PC, if i right clicked and went to "run as administrator" it worked fine, not sure if Windows 8 has that option though or even if it'll do anything